# Statistic : Compare previous value with actual value, database structure

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'd like to be able to tell if the actual value is higher than the previous week (we take -7 calendar days). So i could show the information and its evolution :

[image: status]

For that case i am talking about the status of my work item (post). This is my table (See status and status_last_update):

[image: table]

So to implement this new feature, i am thinking about 2 solutions. I'd like to know which one would be better and the reason for it. Or if there is any better solution.

First solution : i add 2 more columns in my actual table "previous_status" "previous_status_last_update".

Second solution : I create a new table that will store the previous status and the date of its last update.

Third solution : I create a table storing the actual value and previous value :

- nb_new
- nb_new_last_update
- nb_under_discussion
- nb_under_discussion_last_update
- nb_liked
- nb_liked_last_update
- nb_disliked
- nb_disliked_last_update
- nb_approved
- nb_approved_last_update
- nb_rejected
- nb_rejected_last_update
- nb_new_previous
- nb_new_last_update_previous
- nb_under_discussion_previous
- nb_under_discussion_last_update_previous
- nb_liked_previous
- nb_liked_last_update_previous
- nb_disliked_previous
- nb_disliked_last_update_previous
- nb_approved_previous
- nb_approved_last_update_previous
- nb_rejected_previous
- nb_rejected_last_update_previous

Comment: 2 tables with conform to the normilisation standards, but its kind of trivial and may be lazy enough to just add a couple more columns

Answer (score 0):

Why not just insert a little logic into your SQL statement that pulls the data from last week and this week into a single row like this:

```
select
    sub.thisWeekStatus,
    sub.lastWeekStatus,
    sub.someOtherColumn
from
    (
        select
            case
                when dateField=cur_date() then status
            end as thisWeekStatus,
            case
                when dateField<>cur_date() then status
            end as lastWeekStatus,
            someOtherColumn
        from
            yourTable
        where
            dateField>'dateLastWeek'

    ) sub
group by
    sub.someOtherColumn
```

Obviously you need to tinker with it a little, I haven't bothered with the date functions to pull just the last week (or whatever) of data, but this can be adjusted to meet your exact specifications.

Comment: Yes it is probably the plan to do that way but until now i haven't registered any lastWeekStatus. That is why my question was about the database structure, if i should have 2 tables or 1 with more information (columns).

But as Dagon said it is more conform to have 2 tables but kind of trivial.

Thank you anyway for your answer, it might be useful later on.